# How do I recognize a mouseclick in a webpage from a Safari extension?

Tags: javascript, safari, safari-extension

I'm a bit of a noob, but I tried all of the obvious things.  Perhaps my javascript is just terrible and that's why, but onmousedown = func; doesn't work. etc.

```
    function performCommand(event)
{
    /*removed*/
//It reaches this point
        document.body.onclick = function() { 
        //Never reaches this point
/*removed*/
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.onclick

### Summary

The onclick property returns the onClick event handler code on the current element.

### Syntax

```
element.onclick = functionRef;
```

where functionRef is a function - often a name of a function declared elsewhere or a function expression. See Core JavaScript 1.5 Reference:Functions for details.

### Example

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>onclick event example</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function initElement()
 {
 var p = document.getElementById("foo");
 // NOTE: showAlert(); or showAlert(param); will NOT work here.
 // Must be a reference to a function name, not a function call.
 p.onclick = showAlert;
 };

function showAlert()
 {
 alert("onclick Event detected!")
 }
</script>
<style type="text/css">
#foo {
border: solid blue 2px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body onload="initElement()";>
<span id="foo">My Event Element</span>
<p>click on the above element.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Or you can use an anonymous function, like this:

```
p.onclick = function() { alert("moot!"); };
```

(From [the MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.onclick) @ `cc-by-sa`.)

Comment: That's still not working. I don't know why... window.onclick = function() {...}

Comment: @Switz : that should be `document.body.onclick`

Comment: Still not working.  I assume it's because once I click on the button, the script runs through and if the script ends then it will no longer recognize the click..

Comment: @Switz : Entire webpage. Are you sure that `performEvent` is being called?

Comment: performCommand and yes. I'd rather not post the full page as to save my code.  Regardless everything up to that point works, so there's no reason that I can see why it won't other than disallowing it by Apple.